# How to automatically paste text to the end of multiple lines?

Tags: excel, text, proxy, paste, notepad

This probably has a really easy solution that I'm overlooking, but say I have a list of IP addresses that I am using as proxies.

for example:

```
1.1.1.1

2.2.2.2

3.3.3.3

4.4.4.4

5.5.5.5
```

and I need to add authentication to each proxy in the form of `port:user:pass`.

how can I automatically edit the list to look like this without pasting on each line?

```
1.1.1.1:port:user:pass

2.2.2.2:port:user:pass

3.3.3.3:port:user:pass

4.4.4.4:port:user:pass

5.5.5.5:port:user:pass
```

Comment: note: the port:user:pass is the same for every proxy.

Comment: In excel use the CONCATENATE function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use any text editor with a regex replace.

And the regex would be

Find : \s*$

Replace with: " My string to be appended"

If your file is too large to open in a text editor, you can use tools like sed to do the same. Or write a simple program to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

In excel I would do:

```
=A1&":"&"port:user:pass"
```

assuming the data starts in cell A1 then just drag down...

Of course you could have port:user:pass in cell B1 and do:

```
=A1&":"&B1
```

which may give you flexibility to change the text if necessary.;